# How to extract stock code NUMBER from news summary?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a Pandas table and need to extract the stock code '00981',  '00823' from text stored in a column. The code is in the (00000) format.  The code would be located at different location in the text summary.  Please advice.

```
News
1 example（00981）example example example。 
2 example example example （00823）text text text
```

desired output:

```
Code column
981
823

s = TABLE['News'].str.find('（')
e = s + 5
c = TABLE['News'].str[s:e]
TABLE["Code"] = c
```

Comment: So it always has parenthesis around the number? Are there parenthesis in the text not related to stock price?

Comment: Could you post a sample input and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me :

```
print(df)
           News
0          1 example（00981）example example example。 
1      2 example example example （00823）text text...
```

-

```
df['stock_num'] = df['News'].str.extract('(\d{5})').astype(int)
print(df)
                                                    News stock_num
0          1 example（00981）example example example。      981
1      2 example example example （00823）text text...     823
```

to change the string into a number you can either leverage the `.astype()` method or `pd.to_numeric(df['stock_number'])`

Comment: One more thing, how to convert the stock_num into number ie 921, 823?

Answer (score 0):

This will find all occurrences of 5 digits surrounded by parentheses:

```
import re

x = re.findall('\(\d{5}\)', my_string)
```

Comment: (00000) are code format. However,  need to apply to whole column.  x = re.findall('\(\d{5}\)',  df["News"]) and this do not work. Please help.